# Work with QTimer, QThread and Progress Bar

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to use calculation in separate from Ui thread. Calculating method — private slot of MainWindow Метод. During calculations, there is a gradual transfer of the calculated data in object OutputData — field of ProgressBar Window. The thread in which calculations are performed is also a field of the main window.

Main Window constructor, where the thread is created and beginning of calculation is connected to the start of the thread:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
ui->setupUi(this);

calculation = new QThread(this);

settings.setToDefault();
outputData.setToDefault();
calculationDone = false;

connect(calculation, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(calculate()));

ui->results_display->setText("Загрузите <b>параметры</b> и начинайте расчёты!");
}
```

Push button method, starting the thread and modal window w/ ProgressBar:

```
void MainWindow::on_calculate_button_clicked() {
ui->results_display->clear();
ui->results_display2->clear();

calculation->start();

///TODO QProgressDialog

ProgressDialog progressDialog(&outputData, this);
progressDialog.setModal(true);
progressDialog.exec();

if (progressDialog.result() == QDialog::Rejected) {
    calculation->terminate();
    QMessageBox::critical(this, "Результат", "Расчёт был остановлен!");
} else {
    if (progressDialog.result() == QDialog::Accepted) {
        calculation->quit();
        QMessageBox::about(this, "Результат", "Готово!");
        }
    }
}
```

Modal window constructor sets parameters of ProgressBar, creates timer and set connection between timer and update method:

```
ProgressDialog::ProgressDialog(OutputData *outputData, QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::ProgressDialog) {
ui->setupUi(this);

data = outputData;

ui->quantity_label->setText("0");
ui->progressBar->setMinimum(0);
ui->progressBar->setMaximum(static_cast<int>(data->outputSettings.aircraftQuantity));

timer = new QTimer(this);
timer->setSingleShot(false);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
timer->start(50);
}
```

ProgressBar update method:

```
void ProgressDialog::update() {
unsigned long aircraftsDone = data->results.size() + data->unprocessedAircrafts.size();
ui->progressBar->setValue(static_cast<int>(aircraftsDone));
ui->aircraftQunatityDone_label->setText(QString::number(aircraftsDone));
ui->progressBar->repaint();

if (aircraftsDone == data->outputSettings.aircraftQuantity) {
    accept();
   }
}
```

Calculations currently work well, but no progress information is drawn or updated.

Comment: In addition to Rhathin answer, worth reading [Threading basics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html).

Comment: Also, try using QFuture or make use of QThreadPool. There is no need for a dedicated thread when doing a calculation. You should use smart pointers too, std::unique_ptr, shared_ptr, weak_ptr or the Qt alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `calculate` method isn't called in new thread.

To run any method in new thread using `QThread`, you've to move object which this method is public slot of (this object must inherit from `QObject` class) into `QThread` instance using `QObject::moveToThread` and then connect your method with `QThread::started` signal.
In your case, you just set connection between `calculate` slot in `MainWindow` and `QThread::started` signal in `calculation`, so when you call `calculation->start()` then you're firing `calculate` method in the same thread where you called `calculation->start()`.

To fix this, you should create a separate class for your `calculate` method and then move object of this class into your `QThread` inside `MainWindow` constructor.

I recommend you to look at example in [reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details)

Comment: Can OutputData class play role of such "worker" class?

Comment: As long as it inherit from `QObject`, then yes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that no objects do not need to submit to the flow, and it works similar to other programming languages, that is, I can just apply the method to the stream

Comment: Problem solved. Added `virtual` before destructor OutputData and rerun qmake

Answer (score 1):

These are sample code for [Rhathin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52152334/10311171) and [reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details).

`mainwindow.h`

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>
#include "calculationworker.h"
#include "progressdialog.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QThread *calculationThread;
    CalculationWorker *calculationWorker;

signals:
    void startCalculation();
    void stopCalculation();

private slots:
    void on_calculate_button_clicked();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    calculationThread = new QThread( this );
    calculationWorker = new CalculationWorker();

    calculationWorker->moveToThread( calculationThread );

    connect( this, SIGNAL(startCalculation()), calculationWorker, SLOT(calculate()) );
    connect( this, SIGNAL(stopCalculation()), calculationWorker, SLOT(stopCalculation()), Qt::DirectConnection );

    calculationThread->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    calculationThread->quit();
    calculationThread->wait();
    delete calculationWorker;
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_calculate_button_clicked()
{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog( this );
    connect( calculationWorker, SIGNAL(progress(int, int)), &progressDialog, SLOT(progress(int, int)) );
    connect( calculationWorker, SIGNAL(completed()), &progressDialog, SLOT(completed()) );

    emit startCalculation();

    progressDialog.setModal( true );
    progressDialog.exec();

    if ( progressDialog.result() == QDialog::Rejected ) {
        emit stopCalculation();
    } else if ( progressDialog.result() == QDialog::Accepted ) {
        // Accepted
    }
}
```

calculationworker.h

```
#ifndef CALCULATIONWORKER_H
#define CALCULATIONWORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread> // msleep()

class CalculationWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CalculationWorker(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void progress( int processed, int quantity );
    void stopped();
    void completed();

public slots:
    void calculate();
    void stopCalculation();

private:
    bool m_stopFlag;
};

#endif // CALCULATIONWORKER_H
```

calculationworker.cpp

```
#include "calculationworker.h"

CalculationWorker::CalculationWorker(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void CalculationWorker::calculate()
{
    m_stopFlag = false;

    int quantity = 1000;
    for ( int i = 0; i < quantity; i++ ) {
        if ( m_stopFlag ) {
            emit stopped();
            return;
        }

        // Do calculation here
        QThread::msleep( 10 );

        emit progress( i, quantity );
    }

    emit completed();
}

void CalculationWorker::stopCalculation()
{
    m_stopFlag = true;
}
```

progressdialog.h

```
#ifndef PROGRESSDIALOG_H
#define PROGRESSDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class ProgressDialog;
}

class ProgressDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ProgressDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~ProgressDialog();

private:
    Ui::ProgressDialog *ui;

public slots:
    void progress( int processed, int quantity );
    void completed();
};

#endif // PROGRESSDIALOG_H
```

progressdialog.cpp

```
#include "progressdialog.h"
#include "ui_progressdialog.h"

ProgressDialog::ProgressDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ProgressDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

ProgressDialog::~ProgressDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ProgressDialog::progress(int processed, int quantity)
{
    ui->progressBar->setMaximum( quantity );
    ui->progressBar->setValue( processed );
}

void ProgressDialog::completed()
{
    accept();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But I have a slightly different ideology: the counting method should only count and nothing more, it should not report its progress, only that it has completed (stop flag). The Ui should look at the calculated data and analyze it.

Comment: I moved some of the code, but unfortunately I get an error: symbol(s) not found in architecture x86-64, linker command failed with exit code 1

Comment: It appears when I add Q_OBJECT macro in a class that inherits from QObject

Comment: Problem solved. Added virtual before destructor OutputData and rerun qmake

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't understand your code exactly. I have posted [another version sample codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52218711/10311171) that do not emit progress while calculation, using QTimer.

Answer (score 0):

These are another version sample code that do not emit progress while calculation.

`mainwindow.h`

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>
#include "calculationworker.h"
#include "progressdialog.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QThread *calculationThread;
    CalculationWorker *calculationWorker;

signals:
    void startCalculation();

private slots:
    void on_calculate_button_clicked();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    calculationThread = new QThread( this );
    calculationWorker = new CalculationWorker();

    calculationWorker->moveToThread( calculationThread );

    connect( this, SIGNAL(startCalculation()), calculationWorker, SLOT(calculate()) );

    calculationThread->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    calculationThread->quit();
    calculationThread->wait();
    delete calculationWorker;
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_calculate_button_clicked()
{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog( calculationWorker ,this );

    emit startCalculation();

    progressDialog.exec();

    if ( progressDialog.result() == QDialog::Rejected ) {
        // Rejected(Stopped)
    } else if ( progressDialog.result() == QDialog::Accepted ) {
        // Accepted
    }
}
```

calculationworker.h

```
#ifndef CALCULATIONWORKER_H
#define CALCULATIONWORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread> // msleep()

class CalculationWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CalculationWorker(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    int getQuantity();
    int getProcessed();

signals:
    void started();
    void stopped();
    void completed();

public slots:
    void calculate();
    void stopCalculation();

private:
    bool m_stopFlag;
    bool m_stopped;

    int m_processed;
    int m_quantity;
};

#endif // CALCULATIONWORKER_H
```

calculationworker.cpp

```
#include "calculationworker.h"

CalculationWorker::CalculationWorker(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_quantity = 1000;
}

int CalculationWorker::getQuantity()
{
    // Return quantity (data->outputSettings.aircraftQuantity)))
    return m_quantity;
}

int CalculationWorker::getProcessed()
{
    // Return processed (data->results.size() + data->unprocessedAircrafts.size())
    return m_processed;
}

void CalculationWorker::calculate()
{
    m_stopFlag = false;

    emit started();

    // Calculation
    for ( m_processed = 0; m_processed < m_quantity; m_processed++ ) {
        if ( m_stopFlag ) {
            // emit stopped();
            return;
        }

        // Do calculation here
        QThread::msleep( 10 );
    }

    emit completed();
}

void CalculationWorker::stopCalculation()
{
    m_stopFlag = true;
}
```

progressdialog.h

```
#ifndef PROGRESSDIALOG_H
#define PROGRESSDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QTimer>
#include "calculationworker.h"

namespace Ui {
class ProgressDialog;
}

class ProgressDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ProgressDialog( CalculationWorker *worker, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~ProgressDialog();

private:
    Ui::ProgressDialog *ui;
    CalculationWorker *m_worker;
    QTimer *m_progressTimer;

public slots:
    void started();
    void update();
};

#endif // PROGRESSDIALOG_H
```

progressdialog.cpp

```
#include "progressdialog.h"
#include "ui_progressdialog.h"

ProgressDialog::ProgressDialog( CalculationWorker *worker, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ProgressDialog),
    m_worker(worker),
    m_progressTimer(new QTimer(parent))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Connect started signal from worker
    connect( m_worker, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(started()) );

    // Stop calculation by clicking reject button
    connect( this, SIGNAL(rejected()), m_worker, SLOT(stopCalculation()), Qt::DirectConnection );

    // Connect timeout signal to update
    connect( m_progressTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()) );

    // Stop the timer when the dialog is closed
    connect( this, SIGNAL(finished(int)), m_progressTimer, SLOT(stop()) );
}

ProgressDialog::~ProgressDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ProgressDialog::started()
{
    ui->progressBar->setMaximum( m_worker->getQuantity() );
    m_progressTimer->start( 50 );
}

void ProgressDialog::update()
{
    ui->progressBar->setValue( m_worker->getProcessed() );

    if ( m_worker->getProcessed() == m_worker->getQuantity() ) {
        accept();
    }
}
```